# Extracting Elevation (DEM) from air photos using open source software?

Tags: dem, open-source-gis, software-recommendations, stereo-imagery

I have a few pairs of stereo air photos and I want to extract a DEM from them.

I think that is possible using PCI (OrthoEngine), but I would like to do it using Open Source (or at least free) software.

I've looking in GRASS GIS and Orfeo Toolbox but I didn't find how to do it? 
(It is possible that I have not looked correctly...).

Is it possible?

Comment: If the duplicate Q&A does not give you a way forward and you want more help here then I recommend choosing the Open Source GIS option that you think looks most hopeful, install it to see if it meets your requirements and if you get stuck on a requirement then ask a focussed question about that.

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo! I've tried to find a similar question before posting mine, and I couldn't do it. I'll check the options recommended.